# Datagridview displays datatable columns headers without rows

Tags: c#

I have a datagridview named dtgv on my windows Form and I want to populate it from a DataTable. I have created the "remplirdtgv()" method below which works very well when I call it in form_load event. My problem is that, when I call this method after updating the DataTable(adding or removing a row) by clicking on a button, the DataGridview displays only the DataTable columns headers not the rows.
Could someone help me?

```
private void remplirdtgv()
        {
            dtgv.Columns.Clear();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source = .\\mydb.db; version=3;";
            conn.Open();
            try
            {
                SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM mytab ORDER BY tabId", conn);
                SQLiteDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (r.HasRows)
                {
                    dt.Reset();
                    dt.Load(r);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Les données n'ont pas été correctement chargées. \r\n" + e, "Erreur de lecture des données", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            dtgv.DataSource = dt;
            //l1.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString();
            //l2.Text = dtgv.RowCount.ToString();
            r.Close();
        }
```

Comment: `dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());`  `ExecuteReader` executes the SQL command, it doesnt just create a DataReader.

Comment: Your code cannot even compile. The line `r.Close()` is not exposed to the variable r, so it will generate an error. Isn't that `conn.Close()`?

Comment: you are right iSpain17! Thank u! I finally I find the solution. In my initial code, i declared the datatable named "dt" and the datareader "r" out of the remplirdtgv() method. I then use dt.Reset(); to reset the datatable before loading it but that didn't work. It works succesfully when I initialise the datatable inside the method. thanks to All